# How to authentication against Web Api in an angular application without login

Tags: angular, jwt, access-token, webapi

I have an Angular Application and a Web Api. When any user access to the app, he is route to login page and using the user's credentials I create a token (with JWT), with which the application authenticates to consume the api.
However, login is not mandatory any more, users can access to home page directly. So now I have a conceptual question ...
What is the correct way to authenticate against my api for unauthenticated and authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

You should be concern about authorization when you are working on authentication. So you can use authorization to decide for which user you have to authenticate and for whom you don't want to...